# best .net solution for ecommerce compared to Magento CE

Tags: c#, .net, magento, shopping-cart

I am in the need of looking for a .net shopping cart, I am a .net developer not PHP and I need that the shopping cart solution be extendible.

In the past I have used Magento, and its probably the best solution out there, but I dont want just to learn another programming language.

Is there any as good as magento but done in .NET??

Some requirements I need:

- MultiStore in one single database.
- Ability to create themes.
- Complex shopping cart discount rules as in Magento

Comment: may i know what e-commerce you are currently using @ Luis Valencia

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, there are only two written in .NET, and one of them is geared towards MVC.

ASP.NET MVC
http://merchanttribe.com/
http://www.nopcommerce.com `- Version 3.0 and above is now MVC`

ASP.NET
http://www.nopcommerce.com/ `- Version 2.9 and below is web forms`

Comment: After switching to Asp.Net MVC, Nop Commerce is definitely the best open source e-commerce platform out there. Highly recommended!

Answer (score 1):

dashcommerce http://dashcommerce.org/ is also a good option

has evolved from the old Commerce Starter Kit

Comment: __Dead link__, Seems like the project no longer exists in mentioned link

Answer (score 0):

Another one is [OpenNetCommerce](http://opennetcommerce.codeplex.com) from which dashCommerce derived and went commercial. nopCommerce haven't tested lately, but it used to have issues with the speed.