# Products Up- and Download with C# and the Magentostore

Tags: c#, magento

how I am able to do products in the Magentoshop easy products with pictures highly or downloaded. The whole one should be realised with C #. I wand to use SOAP V2. I am grateful for every help.

Comment: so you want to just recieve a webshop form?

Comment: i suggest to take a look at this question, here are some links given to open sourche programms which acts like magento but is made for the .NET platform **not sure if its C#
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531659/best-net-solution-for-ecommerce-compared-to-magento-ce

Answer (score 2):

Isn't easy anyway to get the product information from a mangento shop in your C#-project.

First of all you have to add a `ServiceReference` in you C#-project to connect to the magento soap service.

Working with the SOAP V2 service you have to use something like this

```
http://<your domain>/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl
```

as your `ServiceReference`.

After including the `ServiceReference` you should have an `Interface`
namend `Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeClient` in your Objectexplorer.

Now you are able to communicate with the Magento SOAP Service from your C#-project.

Here a basic sample for the communitaction with the service and getting product information.

Include

```
using <YourSOAPService>.ServiceReference;
```

to your class file. Then try the following.

```
Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeClient client = null;
client = new Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeClient();

if (client.State != System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Opened)
   client.Open();

var sessionID = _client.login(<yourApiUser>, <yourApiPassword>);

catalogProductEntity[] resultArray = null;
client.catalogProductList(out resultArray, sessionID
                                          , new filters(), <storeview>);
```

After running that code you should have an array with all unfilterd products of your magento shop in your C#-project.

In this sample all values in `<>` musst be replaced with your on information.

Comment: what is <storeview>

Answer (score 0):

Magento has three API's:
SOAP V1,
SOAP V2
and RPC.

SOAP V1 is dead and is hard to use from .NET, mostly because it has only few methods and everything is happening through call method, so wsdl isn't telling you the the structure of your data and in .NET some of the data is quite hard to output in required form, using standard service reference client.

SOAP V2 is way better, they have separated calls into separate methods, but haven't tried to use, just saw the wsdl, but you should get much better generated code from service reference.

And RPC - there's a library for it - http://www.molotovbliss.com/net-c-api-to-magento-via-xml-rpc (as far as I remember, they removed last version from web, but in some forums it is still there), so this may be the easiest way to do import/export from magento.

Problem is, that if magento owner made any changes to API, it may be, that he won't support all three methods, as it was in my case.